# Does the Clipper plugin for QGIS work with Shapefile layers?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I created 2 overlapped polygons in one Shapefile layer, run the intersection tool with another layer and then run the Clipper plugin.
This causes the error:

```
TypeError: MultiPolygon geometry cannot be converted to a polygon. 
Only single polygon or curve polygon types are permitted.
```

Well, I decided not to do intersection before the Clipper. But now I've received the same error...

Comment: Is the geometry type of input layer set to `polygon` or to `multipolygon`?

Comment: This is a Shapefile layer. There is no choice there between polygon and multipolygon. I don't need multipolygon, polygon is just fine for me, but I don't know how to change it.

Comment: _Multipart to singleparts_ tool converts the MultiPolygon to Polygon layer.

Comment: Multipart to singleparts tool solves the problem. Thank you very much, Gabriel De Luca